# Не будет ли проблем с памятью?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Суть вопроса:
Есть, скажем, всплывающая вьюшка. Пользователь производит на ней некие действия, после которого в в ее владельце должен быть выполнен некий метод. Можно ли в эту самую вьюшку передать указатель на его владельца и используя этот указатель вызывать методы? Т.е:

view.m

```
 - (void) mainFunctionWithOwner: (SomeClass *) owner {     
    //some code    
    SomeClass *_owner = owner;    
    [_owner someMethod];    
    [self setHidden:YES];

 }
```

Да, я совершенный новичок, но очень хочу учиться, так что простите, если вопрос глупый)

Comment: На первый взгляд все чисто. после завершения mainFunctionWithOwner, если ни кто больше не ссылается на owner он будет удалет из памяти.

Comment: А не проще ли блоки заюзать??

Comment: @svatorus, а зачем Вам локальная переменная `_owner`, если уже есть owner, переданный в качестве аргумента?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, хм, ну да, логично, тупанул

Comment: Как вещает википедия:
Блоки (англ. Blocks) — это добавленное Apple нестандартное расширение языков программирования C/C++/Objective-C, которое использует лямбда-подобный синтаксис для создания замыканий.

http://macbug.ru/cocoa/objc6
http://idev.by/ios/21061/
http://www.imaladec.com/story/blocks

Ну это в кратце, а вообще море статей, особенно на английском.
Я, к примеру, не представляю разработку, без их использования)